# Are commas necessary before and/or after a possessive appositive?

Tags: possessives, commas, appositives

Which is correct:

1. It's my daughter's, Mary's, birthday.
2. It's my daughter, Mary's, birthday.
3. It's my daughter, Mary's birthday.
4. It's my daughter Mary's birthday.

Comment: We need a grammar expert because there are three different answers and it is unlikely that all of us are correct. I think I am right about this, but am no grammar guru. So someone who knows should answer please!

Comment: Why do you put commas in the sentence? Is it requisite?

Answer (score 1):

The first one because the name is an optional information so you need to [mark it off](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/punctuation/comma#commas_to_mark_off_parts_of_a_sentence) and your sentence has to make sense without it, too, hence you need the possessive 's with the word daughter.

> It's my daughter's, Mary's, birthday.
>   It's my daughter's birthday.

Although personally I'd use [em dashes](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/punctuation/dash-and-em-dash) here to avoid having commas so close to apostrophes.

> It's my daughter's—Mary's—birthday.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is one of those questions that only an expert can answer. So I asked and @userr2684291 sent me to grammarbook. Thanks!

However, in common usage, we can share what we see . I don't see what a comma adds to any of these examples. Mary + daughter need no separation. They aren't listed. There are no separate thoughts that are being joined.

If today is Mary's birthday, we can say it a few  ways.

It is Mary's birthday.

It is my daughter's birthday.

It is my daughter Mary's birthday.

Okay I went and asked. [LINK](http://data.grammarbook.com/blog/commas/commas-with-appositives/)

> Rule: When an appositive is essential to the meaning of the noun it
>   belongs to, don’t use commas. When the noun preceding the appositive
>   provides sufficient identification on its own, use commas around the
>   appositive.

Example: My friend Harvey is an animal lover.
Explanation: My friend is not a precise identifier because one may have numerous friends.

Example: Harvey, my friend, loves animals.
Explanation: Harvey is a precise identifier.

So: It is my daughter Mary's birthday. (You have more than one daughter.)

It is my daughter, Mary's, birthday. (You have only one daughter.)

Comment: [Apposition - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition): _A non-restrictive appositive provides information not critical to identifying the phrase in apposition. It provides non-essential information, and the essential meaning of the sentence would not change if the appositive were removed._ However, we can't remove the appositive in your last example as we have both an appositive and a possessive.

Answer (score 1):

1. It's my daughter's, Mary's, birthday.  <- This one is wrong. It's either "my daughter's birthday" or My daughter Mary's birthday - never "My daughter's Mary's."
2. It's my daughter, Mary's, birthday.  <- This might not be technically wrong, but it is very awkward.
3. It's my daughter, Mary's birthday.  <- This is wrong. It's two unrelated phrases when you put the comma there "It's my daughter" and "Mary's birthday."
4. It's my daughter Mary's birthday.  <- This is the most natural. This is how I would write it.

For what it's worth, I'm a native speaker and a Librarian.

Answer (score -2):

It should be "It's my daughter's, Mary's, birthday."

[Commas](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/commas.asp)

Rule 6. If something or someone is sufficiently identified, the description that follows is considered nonessential and should be surrounded by commas.

Comment: Not necessarily. If the speaker had more than one daughter, then they have NOT been sufficiently identified, and it is not non-essential. Also, two possessive s's is incorrect.

Comment: @Harukogirl "I am going to my Father's friend's house." I don't think this is incorrect use of two possessives. Despite they came in a row. And, could you please explain why my answer was down-voted and not of Korin's?

Comment: No idea - I didn't down vote anything :)

Comment: @Harukogirl - Could you please explain "Also, two possessive s's is incorrect" ?